# Add blank lines to XElement preserving other formatting

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xelement

I have an XElement that I constructed in code. It has (conceptually) 2 groups of nodes. If I just print it out, I get a nicely formatted Xml file, but with all the nodes together. If I add a couple of newlines between the 2 groups for easier human comprehension, I lose all the formatting following it.
How can I add a small break between the 2 groups, and still keep the rest of the formatting?

**Example:**
This is the default:

```
<root>
  <node>1.1</node>
  <node>1.2</node>
  <node>2.1</node>
  <node>2.2</node>
</root>
```

This is if I add the break:

```
<root>
  <node>1.1</node>
  <node>1.2</node>

<node>2.1</node><node>2.2</node></root>
```

This is what I want:

```
<root>
  <node>1.1</node>
  <node>1.2</node>

  <node>2.1</node>
  <node>2.2</node>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you add how you print this out? Are you using XmlWriterSettings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950019/spacing-out-output-with-linq-to-xml). I have the impression it's not possible with a clean solution. I tried several ways, to no avail. I also looked into the System.Linq.Xml source code, but can't really find why it does this.

Another option is to do the `ToString` first, and then to add the newlines after that (with a replace, if you know which nodes need the newline):

```
result = result.Replace("<parentNode>", Environment.NewLine + "<parentNode>");
```

But that will probably muck up your indenting again.